# Bug in XmlRootAttribute for generic Method in C#

Tags: c#, xml, generics, deserialization

I try to deserialize an xml after serialization of it.

The Method looks like this:

```
public List<T> DeSerialize<T>(string Address)
{
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>), new XmlRootAttribute("ArrayOfClassName"));
    List <T> result;

    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@Folder + Address + ".xml", FileMode.Open))
    {
        result = (List<T>)deserializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
    }

    return result;
}
```

It works as long as i let the

```
XmlRootAttribute("ArrayOfClassName")
```

be pre defined string.
As soon as i change it to to a more generic aproach like:

```
XmlRootAttribute(typeof(List<T>).Name)
```

or

```
XmlRootAttribute("ArrayOf" + typeof(T).Name)
```

I do get

> System.InvalidOperationException: "There is an error in XML
>   document(1,2.)" with the InvalidOperationException:  was not expected hint.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: InvalidOperationException: ArrayOfCoinTransactionBitCoin xmlns='' was not expected.

Comment: and where's your xml?

Comment: @Hunselfunsel - You wrote, *Found my error, it was somewhere else. I dont know how to delete a question.*  if you want to delete your own question (as you mentioned you did in your now-deleted answer) see [How can I delete my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42265).